# How to enqueue script to archive head with themes' function.php?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, themes

In my theme there is a the category.php template for the archives of certain categories. I modified this file but to have an effect I need to add some javascript to the head of category.php file. Within that file there is the expression `get_header();`

I opened my themes' header.php and saw that all script files seem to be initialized by this function: `wp_head();`

So I guess I'll have to modify my theme's functions.php to enqueue my script to the head of the archive template.

But how to do that? How could I filter for category.php? During my research I found this function: `is_category()` - but it works only for template files. I was able to add my javascript files to the head by adding this to my header.php below the `wp_head();` function:

```
if(is_category()){    
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.get_bloginfo("wpurl").'/wp-content/themes/my_theme/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'.'"></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.get_bloginfo("wpurl").'/wp-content/themes/my_theme/js/my_script.js'.'"></script>';        
}
```

This works but doesn't seem to be the elegant/proper way to do it. I read several times that one always should use `enqueue_script` functions to add script. So what is best practice and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. You'll want to enqueue the scripts, but only if you're on a category archive page. Also, WordPress [includes jQuery by default](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress), so there's no reason to include your own. Keep in mind that this will mean you'll need to adhere to the [noConflict mode wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

```
function enqueue_my_so_scripts() {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_script.js', array('jquery'));
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_so_scripts' );
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked, thank you very much! About jQuery - without enqueuing my jQuery script my_script doesn't work. But I think there is a method to replace the default jQuery by a newer version. I'll check that out.

Comment: Yeah, you're looking for [wp_deregister_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) <-- That link has good info on deregistering jquery. You'll then just want to "enqueue" your own jquery (and name it 'jquery') of course.